# I have get trouble when use fmod to setMusicSpeed()

Tags: fmod

I have a MID file to play,and it spend 10s in normal speed.but when I call setMusicSpeed() to set 0.1,it also stop after 10s. I want to know why and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have get email from FMOD support.To get around this, you should set the length of the stream to infinite length, using FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO and set length value to (unsigned int)-1;and it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Hm. Maybe you forget to call system->Update(); Also, try linking with the logging version of FMOD.

Comment: haha,it's fixed.I have receive from FMOD support.show to you,To get around this, you should set the length of the stream to infinite length, using FMOD_CREATESOUNDEXINFO and set length value to (unsigned int)-1;it's works.